# Selenium: How to set browser in offline mode?

Tags: selenium

I need to test a feature of my app designed to execute in offline mode, using local storage to queue data before internet connectivity is restored. Can Selenium set browser in offline mode?

Answer (score 1):

You can create the new Browser Profile say for firefox.
and then configure that profile to use offline mode
using :

network.manage-offline-status with the value true.

Comment: Can I set the profile dynamically? I want to simulate a scenario where the app loses connectivity during usage.

Comment: No.  Profiles are set at the beginning only.  You could try other non-selenium tricks to lose connection, however (if you are going to run selenium remotely, that won't work).

Comment: If you try this, you will get the following exception: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Preference network.manage-offline-status may not be overridden: frozen value=false, requested value=true