# Selenium set Browser Chrome in OffLine mode

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, selenium

I am testing a Javascript application in Chrome browser. I want to load the page, and once loaded I would like to switch the browser to offline mode.

[image]

Note that I DON´T want to start the browser in offline mode as mentioned here: [Selenium: How to set browser in offline mode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18175619/selenium-how-to-set-browser-in-offline-mode). Instead I want to start the browser connected and then switch it off and a specific moment.

Note that I don´t want to do it manually with the mouse, because this is for creating an automated test with Selenium. So I need to be able to send the instruction to go offline somehow with a script.

Is there anyway using Chrome to do that? could I modify the browser configuration executing a javascript? (probably not for security reasons but still wondering)

Thanks very much for your help.

Answer (score 4):

In Python, this can be achieved like this:

```
driver.set_network_conditions(offline=True, latency=5, throughput=500 * 1024)
```

PS: I am using ChromeDriver 2.32.

Answer (score 2):

As was written in of. release [notes](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.29/notes.txt):

> **ChromeDriver v2.26 (2016-12-09)**
>
> Resolved issue 984: Extend ChromeDriver capabilities to cover network
> throttling feature from Chrome DevTools [['OS-All', 'Pri-2']]

[Here](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=984) is full history log about this task.
But there is no example, and no answer how it works.

Answer (score 1):

In Java, you can use the following code to turn off the WiFi:

```
protected void disConnectInternet() throws IOException {
Map map = new HashMap();
map.put("offline", true);
map.put("latency", 5);
map.put("download_throughput", 500);
map.put("upload_throughput", 1024);


CommandExecutor executor = ((ChromeDriver)driver).getCommandExecutor();
Response response = executor.execute(
        new Command(((ChromeDriver)driver).getSessionId(), "setNetworkConditions", ImmutableMap.of("network_conditions", ImmutableMap.copyOf(map))));

}
```

Comment: How would you reset network conditions afterwards?

Answer (score -1):

You should be able to switch between online and offline mode using this:

```
browser.driver.setNetworkConnection(
  typeOrAirplaneMode: 0|1|2|3|4|5|6|7|boolean, wifi?: boolean, data?: boolean
);
```

More info here: http://webdriver.io/api/mobile/setNetworkConnection.html

Comment: the op is about selenium